# How to extract specific lines in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, object, startswith

I have a pandas's df that is:

```
df['timestamp']
26600          58161.0
26628    58161.0416667
26656    58161.0833333
26684        58161.125
26712    58161.1666667
26740    58161.2083333
26768         58161.25
26796    58161.2916667
26824    58161.3333333
26852        58161.375
26880    58161.4166667
26908    58161.4583333
26936          58162.0
26964    58162.0416645
26992    58162.0833333
```

I would like to extract only the two rows that end with ".0"

I have tried with this command:

```
df['timestamp'].str.startswith(".0", na=False)
```

but it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Is there a simple way to do this job?

Thanks

Comment: What is the dtype of this column?

Comment: Interesting error, but `df['timestamp'].astype(str).str.endswith(".0", na=False)` shoud works

Comment: `print(df[df["TimeStamp"].str.endswith(".0", na=False)])` working for me

Answer (score 5):

If `timestamp` is numeric, you can use modulo `%`:

```
df.loc[df.timestamp % 1 == 0]

           timestamp
index           
26600    58161.0
26936    58162.0
```

If it is not numeric to start with, you can do the same, but convert first:

```
df.loc[df.timestamp.astype(float) % 1 == 0]
```

Comment: Do you think it would be possible extract also the line that ends with 0.5 combinig togheter % 1 == 0 and % 1 == 0.5? Thanks

Comment: @Andrea, yup! go ahead and add that coniditon inside `.loc[]`

Comment: @MattR Unfortunately in this way  df.loc[df.timestamp % 1 == 0 and df.timestamp % 1 == 0.5] doesn't work

Comment: @Andrea, take a look at [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). TL;DR `&` is `and`. `|` is `or`. `~` is `not`

Answer (score 3):

One way is to compare your `float` series to an `int` version:

```
df.loc[df[df['timestamp'] == df['timestamp'].astype(int)]
```